# MongoDB atomically increase today's view count

Tags: mongodb

Here is our collection schema:

```
{ "_id" : "58b7962541afa5136857abbe", "Title": "...", "Content": "...", "Views": 10, "TodayViews": 5 }
```

We need to record total view count and today's view count for this document.
So the question is how can we increase today's view count atomically?

I think about using $slice and $inc operator for a embedded array that limit it's length to 1, but seems MongoDB doesn't support this.

We are using .Net Driver, but native javascript code is fine.

Comment: Why `$slice` if both `Views` and `TodayViews` are integers? `$inc` both and you're done

Comment: @malarzm `Views` is total view count from create date to now, `TodayViews` is today's view count only